# Element Silverlight is not a known element

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight

I'm using Silverlight 3 in Visual Studio 2008.
Unfortunately I can't seem to get the `<asp:Silverlight>` element to work, it's not on the intellisense and it underlines it saying its not a known element.

I'm beginning to think something wasn't installed properly.
Although I've reinstalled the Microsoft® Silverlight™ 3 Tools for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and I'm pretty sure that's what is meant to include asp:silverlight.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Silverlight 3 the Silverlight ASP.NET server control is discontinued, you need to write the `<object>` tag approach into your page instead.

Comment: I stopped using the ASP.NET control a while ago, it really didn't do a whole lot for you and didn't work with ASP.NET MVC. There's been some talk about open sourcing the ASP.NET control, not sure where that stands right now.

Comment: @Bill: Creating a server control for it is pretty straight-forward and allows you to tailor the control to your own frameworl.  An MVC helper would be welcome.